# How to hide elements contained in a div and enable a scroll with a swipe action?

Tags: css, html

In my application, I have a container (a `<div>`) that contains several elements (*boxes*).
The width of the container is limited, and potentially, I have too many boxes inside to display all of them at the same time.
What I want is to let the user "swipe" (as it is a mobile application) to see the rest of the elements.

To summarize, I want something like that:

```
+--------------------------------------+ <- (the container)
|                                      |
| +-----------+ +-----------+ +--------|
| |  Box one  | |  Box two  | | Box Thr|
| +-----------+ +-----------+ +--------|
|                                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Then, if the user wants to see the rest of the boxes, it has to swipe on the `container` box:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|                                      |
|------+ +-----------+ +-----------+ +-|
| one  | |  Box two  | | Box Three | | |
|------+ +-----------+ +-----------+ +-|
|                                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

until he reaches the end of the `container`:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|                                      |
|------+ +------------+ +------------+ |
| two  | |  Box three | |  Box Four  | |
|------+ +------------+ +------------+ |
|                                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Preferably, I would like to avoid displaying an horizontal scroll bar.

For the moment, I have only a basic example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/alHOLCGMiz0qeCRDUFHs?p=preview

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Box one</div>
    <div class="box">Box two</div>
    div class="box">Box three</div>
    <div class="box">Box four</div>
    <div class="box">Box five</div>
</div>
```

and:

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

.box {
    border: solid 1px green;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

But of course, the boxes are all displayed, on several lines, which is not what I want.

How can I achieve that (I mean essentially the diplay part, I will take the "swipe" action on my side)?

I don't know if it matters, but the `swipe` action will be managed by HammerJS.

Answer (score 1):

I know its not exactly what you asked, but i faced this problems some weeks ago.
Like you i wanted to create the scroll effect with swipe events, but i guess its not a good way, i find some bugs in ios7 and after all i gave up and back do `overflow: auto;`

I suggest you to change the scroll style, to be thinner for example.
I did an example for you.. take a look.
http://jsfiddle.net/ethpn/
The code is below.

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;        
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 2px;
}

/* Track */
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { 
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

Comment: Ok, in fact I think I will not go for a `scrollbar`, but what was missing in my configuration was `white-space: nowrap`. Then, I will dynamically change the position of the box on the `swipe` event. Thanks for the inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: If you edit my Plunker example to set `overflow-x` to `scroll`, you will see that it just display a scrollbar, and that's all. It's not working.

Comment: ohh i'm sorry i havent seen that you dont want a scroll bar... but how does the user know that it can be scrolled...???

Comment: That's another problem ;o) But even with your solution, the scrollbar is displayed, but the boxes are displayed on 2 lines, which is not good (even if I want a scrollbar).